# MIPS 32 Program: Array of random integers

Tags: mips, mips32

I'm trying to have a program that makes an array of 12 random integers between the numbers 58 to 768. I'm not sure how to modify this to make the minimum value of 58 and save it to an array. It can generate integers to the spacestr but I'm not sure how to make it go to an array and set a minimum value.

```
.data
spacestr: .asciiz " "
array: .space 48

.text
# get the time
li $v0, 30 # gets time in milliseconds
syscall

move $t0, $a0

# seed the random generator (just once)
li $a0, 1 # random generator id
move $a1, $t0 # seed from time
li $v0, 40 # seed random number generator syscall
syscall

# seeding done

# generate 12 random integers from the seeded generator
li $t2, 13 # max number of iterations + 1
li $t3, 0 # current iteration number

LOOP:
li $a0, 1 # id is the same as random generator id
li $a1, 768 # upper bound of range
li $v0, 42 # random int range ???
syscall

# $a0 holds the random number

# loop terminating condition
addi $t3, $t3, 1 # increment the number of iterations
beq $t3, $t2, EXIT # branch to EXIT if iterations is 12

#a0 still holds random number so print it
li $v0, 1 # print integer syscall
syscall

# print a space
la $a0, spacestr # load the address of the string
li $v0, 4 # print string syscall
syscall

# do another iteration
j LOOP

# exit program
EXIT:

li $v0, 10 # exit syscall
syscall
```

Comment: Add the minimum value after the random number has been generated.

Comment: @Michael how would I be able to save these values to an array?

Comment: By using one of the store instructions.

Comment: @Michael how can I go about with the store instructions?

Comment: Start with a working example and edit it as needed.  There's lots of small sample programs that enter user data into an array and choose min or max, etc..

Comment: @ErikEidt I just need help with how to store the values from the loop into the array.

Comment: Well, like I said, one of those samples will show you that and more.